# Rails slug for ancestry model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, tree, slug

I have ancestry for my category model. Im using slug gem.
Currently i have following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  slug :name
end


class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  defaults :finder => :find_by_slug
  def show
    @category = Category.find_by_slug(params['category_id'])
    show!
  end
end

  match "categories/:category_id" => 'categories#show', :as => :category
```

This works fine, but i want to show **parent/children** path instead of **/children**

if my category have parent. How to reach this?

For example i have BMW category and x5 as subcategory.
 I have now this links: `/categories/bmw` for bmw and `/categories/x5` for x5. i need this link  `categories/bmw/x5` instead of subcategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match "categories/:category_id" => 'categories#show', :as => :category_short
match "categories/:category/:category_id" => 'categories#show', :as => :category_long

  def category_path(category)
    unless category.is_root?
      category_long_path category.parent, category
    else
      category_short_path category
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your `match`statement in your parent resource like this (in Rails 3 at least):

```
resources :things do
  match "categories/:category_id" => 'categories#show', :as => :category
end
```

This should create a route like `/things/:thing_id/categories/:category_id`

Comment: i dont need things, i need *categories/category/:subcategory* or *categories/category* if parent